# Adjusting UILabel height depending on contents?

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel, constraints

I have a custom CollectionViewCell class, which contains a label and an image. Basically, the image will be constrained to the left, top and right of the cell. However, I want its height to vary depending on the height of the UILabel, which in turns is going to be dependent on the contents inside it. Below is my attempt at it:

import UIKit

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {

    super.init(frame: frame)

    backgroundColor = .yellow

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

}

convenience init(cellTextTile text: String) {

    self.init()

}

func setupCustomCellElements(cellImageName image: String, cellTitleTextColour textColour: UIColor, cellTitleTextSize textSize: CGFloat, cellTitleFontType fontType: String, cellTitle title: String) {

    let cellImage: UIImageView = {

        let imageView = UIImageView()

        imageView.backgroundColor = .clear

        imageView.image = UIImage(named: image)

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return imageView

    }()

    let cellTitle: UILabel = {

        let label = UILabel()

        label.textColor = textColour

        label.font = UIFont(name: fontType, size: textSize)

        label.text = title

        label.textAlignment = .center

        label.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)

        label.numberOfLines = 0

        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

        label.sizeToFit()

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return label

    }()

    addSubview(cellImage)

    addSubview(cellTitle)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        cellTitle.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),

        cellTitle.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),

        cellTitle.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),

        cellImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellTitle.topAnchor),

        cellImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),

        cellImage.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),

        cellImage.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor)

        ])

}
```

}

However, with the above code I am not getting the kind of behaviour I am looking for. I want the height of the UIlabel to change based on its contents. And in turn the height of the image to adjust accordingly?

Regards,
Shadi.

Comment: what you get ?.

Comment: The height of the UILabel does not get changed and thus the height of the image is not changing either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a height constraint for the imageView

```
cellImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50), // or any value
```

Also don't add the properties inside the method `setupCustomCellElements` make them an instance variables , and add them inside the `init` function

---

It's better also to add the views to

```
contentView.addSubview(cellImage) 
contentView.addSubview(cellTitle)
```

and constrcut the constraints with it

Comment: Thanks a lot thats exactly what I did and it sorted my problem. I used a constant value, which I created a function for to calulate :)